# CSS Div Relative Positions

Tags: css, html

Is it possible to create layout like on that mockup?

[image: neccessary behaviour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="layout">
    <span id="click">Click me</span
    <div id="mydiv"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.layout {position:relative;height:200px}
#mydiv {width:100px; height:50px;bottom:0}
```

**JS**

```
$("#click").click(function(){
    $("#mydiv").css("position", "absolute");
});
```